# How to set a service that will run a jar file on aws ec2 ubuntu 16.04 instance

Tags: linux, bash, amazon-web-services, ubuntu

I hope you can help me with a problem that I encounter while trying to set a service that will run a jar file on aws ec2 ubuntu 16.04 instance ..
this is the output that I get after running systemctl status demo.service

> ● demo.service - demo
>   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/demo.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
>
> Active: inactive (dead) since Fri 2018-07-13 10:38:19 IDT; 14s ago
>   Process: 1077 ExecStop=/usr/local/bin/demo.sh stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
>
> Process: 1063 ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/demo.sh start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
>
> Jul 13 10:38:19 ip-172-31-38-145 systemd[1]: Starting demo...
>
> Jul 13 10:38:19 ip-172-31-38-145 demo.sh[1063]: Starting demo ...
>
> Jul 13 10:38:19 ip-172-31-38-145 demo.sh[1063]: demo started ...
>
> Jul 13 10:38:19 ip-172-31-38-145 demo.sh[1077]: demo stoping ...
>
> Jul 13 10:38:19 ip-172-31-38-145 demo.sh[1077]: /usr/local/bin/demo.sh: 20: kill: No such process
>
> Jul 13 10:38:19 ip-172-31-38-145 demo.sh[1077]: demo stopped ...
>
> Jul 13 10:38:19 ip-172-31-38-145 systemd[1]: Started demo.

since I am running a spring boot app that listens on port 443 I have to run it as sudo and when I add the sudo before the nohup command I get this ..

> ● demo.service - demo
>   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/demo.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
>
> Active: inactive (dead) since Fri 2018-07-13 10:53:33 IDT; 3s ago
>   Process: 1439 ExecStop=/usr/local/bin/demo.sh stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
>
> Process: 1433 ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/demo.sh start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
>
> Jul 13 10:53:33 ip-172-31-38-145 systemd[1]: Starting demo...
>
> Jul 13 10:53:33 ip-172-31-38-145 demo.sh[1433]: Starting demo ...
>
> Jul 13 10:53:33 ip-172-31-38-145 demo.sh[1433]: demo started ...
>
> Jul 13 10:53:33 ip-172-31-38-145 sudo[1434]: root : TTY=unknown ; PWD=/ ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/nohup java -jar /demo.jar /tmp
>
> Jul 13 10:53:33 ip-172-31-38-145 sudo[1434]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
>
> Jul 13 10:53:33 ip-172-31-38-145 sudo[1434]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
>
> Jul 13 10:53:33 ip-172-31-38-145 demo.sh[1439]: demo stoping ...
>
> Jul 13 10:53:33 ip-172-31-38-145 demo.sh[1439]: /usr/local/bin/demo.sh: 20: kill: No such process
>
> Jul 13 10:53:33 ip-172-31-38-145 demo.sh[1439]: demo stopped ...
>
> Jul 13 10:53:33 ip-172-31-38-145 systemd[1]: Started demo.

my file   /usr/local/bin/demo.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
SERVICE_NAME=demo
PATH_TO_JAR=/demo.jar
PID_PATH_NAME=/tmp/demo-pid
case $1 in
    start)
        echo "Starting $SERVICE_NAME ..."
        if [ ! -f $PID_PATH_NAME ]; then
            sudo nohup java -jar $PATH_TO_JAR /tmp 2>> /dev/null >> /dev/null &
                        echo $! > $PID_PATH_NAME
            echo "$SERVICE_NAME started ..."
        else
            echo "$SERVICE_NAME is already running ..."
        fi
    ;;
    stop)
        if [ -f $PID_PATH_NAME ]; then
            PID=$(cat $PID_PATH_NAME);
            echo "$SERVICE_NAME stoping ..."
            kill $PID;
            echo "$SERVICE_NAME stopped ..."
            rm $PID_PATH_NAME
        else
            echo "$SERVICE_NAME is not running ..."
        fi
    ;;
    restart)
        if [ -f $PID_PATH_NAME ]; then
            PID=$(cat $PID_PATH_NAME);
            echo "$SERVICE_NAME stopping ...";
            kill $PID;
            echo "$SERVICE_NAME stopped ...";
            rm $PID_PATH_NAME
            echo "$SERVICE_NAME starting ..."
            sudo  nohup java -jar $PATH_TO_JAR /tmp 2>> /dev/null >> /dev/null &
                        echo $! > $PID_PATH_NAME
            echo "$SERVICE_NAME started ..."
        else
            echo "$SERVICE_NAME is not running ..."
        fi
    ;;
esac
```

and my file with execution permissions in /etc/systemd/system/demo.service

```
[Unit]
Description=demo
After=syslog.target

[Service]
Type = forking
ExecStart = /usr/local/bin/demo.sh start
ExecStop = /usr/local/bin/demo.sh stop
ExecReload = /usr/local/bin/demo.sh reload


[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

pleas advice .. :)

Answer (score 2):

So I was trying to run a spring boot applications on a AWS EC2 instance as a service and found some pretty nice small bags preventing me reaching my goal ..

1. use always an [absolute directory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing))
2. write your keystore directory ( which different services are using ) in the spring boot application.property file referred to the instant directory and not to your project even though the keystore.p12 file was located in the project .

> server.port=443
>
> server.ssl.key-store=/home/ubuntu/keystore.p12
>
> server.ssl.key-store-password=changeme
>
> server.ssl.keyStoreType=PKCS12
>
> server.ssl.keyAlias= tomcat

3.keep your service unit file ( /etc/systemd/system/demo.service) clean and simple and use the absolute path here also .

[a great how to with a simple explanation](https://www.tecmint.com/create-new-service-units-in-systemd/)

> ```
> [Unit]
> Description=demo
> After=syslog.target
>
> [Service]
> ExecStart = /home/ubuntu/scripts/demo.sh
>
> [Install]
> WantedBy=multi-user.target
> ```

4. keep your bash / script file (/scripts/demo.sh) clean and simple and no need to run the command as a nohup to keep it running in the background .

> ```
> #!/bin/bash
> sudo java -jar /home/ubuntu/demo.jar
> ```

I found also that the error regarding to the port been equipped by a different program once the spring boot shouts is not really true once you try to run an encrypted connection . in my case it was connected to the keystore file and its location not just in this case .

enjoy ..

Answer (score 0):

You can use rc.local in ubuntu ec2 instance to start the application(.jar) on startup. Simply you have to include your .jar executable execution code in rc.local before the `exit 0` line as below, To modify rc.local you should have root access. Therefore access it as follows,
 `sudo vi /etc/rc.local`

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.
# Example Code Execution

java -jar sampleExecutionPackage.jar 

exit 0
```

After that if you need to check the status of the running application you can check that using,

```
sudo systemctl status rc-local.service
```

You can use `start/stop/restart` instead of `status` for the corresponding use of it.

Comment: ]: APPLICATION FAILED TO START
]: ***************************
]: Description:
]: The Tomcat connector configured to listen on port 443 failed to start. The port may already in use .... this is why Im using the sudo command but still threw the rc.local it fails to run even though I wrote  > sudo java -jar demo.jar

Comment: This is not something regarding AWS web services, this occurs because of the 443 port is not available. Therefore check whether the port is available and if not kill the process which occupies that port and try again.

Comment: ok .. I also think that its not but it is relevant since I am running a jre on a linux that is constrained .I checked all ports ( sudo netstat -pan) and the port is not been used and I also got the same error. tried also with a different port (8081) that does not need a sudo permission since in is not a low number of port  but still the same error .. I almost sure there is something connected to the spring boot .I had this error for not placing the certificate in the right root ( go figure that .. ) . running it from the command line works fine .. still . something is missing .